# Gson Serialize to specific fields even if it is null

Tags: java, json, gson

I have requirement where I need to convert java object to json.

I am using Gson for that but i need to serialize the required fields even there is no value i.e null

For example:

```
public class Response<T> 
{
   private String status;
   private String message;
   private T data;
   transient private String resource;
}
```

Even the data is empty or null, i want it to be serialized to json data with empty values.

Objects:

> new Response("success", null , null)
>     ,new Response(null, null , null)

Wanted output:-
 `{ status : "success", data : {}}
 {data : {}}`

Comment: see my answer to this question in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070666/gson-ignores-my-fields-while-converting/44072069#44072069

Comment: @hsl I want to serialize some fields only not all fields

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean by that. can you update the question with some expected input and output so I can get a better understanding?

Comment: try using a custom serializer. here's a working example of what you need: https://gist.github.com/hsl43/e1287961ca7ba03d6cfde02be661042b

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45880993/2066936

Answer (score 0):

Try `serializeNulls()`.

> Configure Gson to serialize null fields. By default, Gson omits all
>   fields that are null during serialization.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();  
gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();  
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

User user = new User("Sankar", null, 25);  
String userJson = gson.toJson(user);
```

Output is:

```
{
  "age": 25,
  "email": null,
  "name": "Sankar"
}
```

Comment: I want to serialize specific fields only, not all fields.